# Shimano Ultegra 6800 front derailleur tension problem

Tags: shimano, derailleur, shifting, derailleur-front

I'm building up a 2015 Salsa Colossal Ti with a full Ultegra 6800 groupset (though with the RS685 hydraulic shifters).  I'm having an issue setting up the front derailleur.  I've followed all the various tutorials online, but whatever I do, I can't seem to get the cable tension right.  Too little tension and I can't get the derailleur to hit the high limit screw.  But when I add the necessary tension, then the derailleur won't hit the low limit screw.  I either have chain rub in the 50/11 or in the 34/32.

I even have the little plastic tool that tells you whether the converter should be on or off (off in my case).  Out of desperation, I've tried the other converter setting, but no luck.

The factory built bike from Salsa comes with the same Ultegra components (apart from the RS685 shifters), so I know I should be able to get this to work.  Am I making some rookie mistake?

Comment: Is there no micro barrel adjustment on those shift cables? Are you adjusting the cable by simply tightening the derailleur clamp in different cable locations? I would imagine it is touchy so as to be just almost perfect and hard to do without the ability to make a micro adjustment. I personally do not yet have experience on those newer hydraulic models though.

Comment: Yes, I have a barrel shifter on the the frame.  I can fine tune the tension.  My problem is that it's either too low to hit the high limit or too high to hit the low limit.  Feel like I must be doing something totally wrong.

Answer (score 3):

The rotational position and height not being exactly right would cause this. Shimano now has a more specific procedure then in the past to establish them, which you can see starting on page 5 of the [dealer manual.](http://si.shimano.com/#/en/DM/FD0002)

If following the procedure in their manual to a T doesn't work, the other thing you may be looking at is a situation such as Lennard Zinn describes in [his column on 11-speed Shimano road FD setup](http://www.velonews.com/2015/03/bikes-and-tech/technical-faq/technical-faq-shimano-11-speed-front-derailleur-cable-setup_363733) where the cable anchor has to be set in an unorthodox position going over the top of the bolt. The dealer manual demonstrates this as a thing you're not supposed to do on the page 14, the two graphics on the right hand side of the chart. It may be worth a try.

As is pointed out further down in that column, problems with these derailers almost always revolve around not having enough cable tension. All aspects of the setup have little if any margin for error and they need as much cable tension as possible. They also need the low limit screw set super close. That  0-0.5mm inner cage clearance number on page 15 of the manual is one that's been around for a while and used to be more or less unrealistic, but they mean business now. It has to be all but touching, and it will work better if it's almost kinda sorta touching (the "0" end of the range). Usually it's the case that if you set it up in the stand for the chain to just barely touch the cage sometimes in the low gear, it won't rub when you're actually climbing because the chain is under so much more tension.

Comment: I do have the dealer manual and I feel like I've followed all the suggestions.  I even have the chain "kinda sorta touching" like you said.  My issue seems to be that with high tension, there's not enough spring tension to pull the derailleur back to the low limit screw.  I checked out the Lennard Zinn article.  I'm a little lost in the technical detail at the end, but I'll definitely try the different cable mounting option.

Comment: Just to double check, you're familiar with the trim stops on the shifter? I think it has one for each ring.

Comment: Yes, I know about the trim stops and they seem to function correctly.  I believe I'm clicking all the way up or all the way down.  First time setting up Shimano though.  I'm used to SRAM.

Comment: So you say you seem to be short on derailer spring tension and the derailer isn't returning to the low position. If you downshift, see it's not returning all the way, and then shove it over the rest of the way with your hands, does it stay?

Comment: If I shove it over the rest of the way and then let go, then it doesn't stay.  It moves back to it's original position.  If I release some tension then it will hit the stop and stay, but then I have problems on the other end.

Comment: And just to be clear, the crank is an FC-6800? On a side note, with the nature of these FDs wanting so much tension, it's not actually  important that it's hitting against the low limit screw per se. In theory the limit screw doesn't even have to be there, as long as the static cable tension is enough. (I don't recommend riding like that in case slackness develops and you throw the chain.) Also, is the chain facing correctly, logo side out?

Comment: Yup, it's an FC-6800.  Everything is standard Ultegra 6800 apart from the shifters, which are the hydraulic RS685.  I know for sure they are Ultegra compatible though.  Bottom bracket is BB86.  I had a thought that maybe there's an issue at the shifter where it's not releasing enough cable.  I wonder if there's any chance I threaded the cable wrong.  Pretty sure I followed the instructions and clicked the small lever more than 4 times before threading.  Am I meant to lube either the cable or the shifter mechanism?  1 more thing - I used the housing ends with the pigtails as shown in the manual

Comment: You shouldn't really have to add any lube when it's all new, although if the housings weren't pre-lubed I would go ahead and add it with 11. It is possible to install the cable incorrectly with these, although usually that would be more like a clear jam. Probably worth a second look though. Are you sure you have the cable routed correctly at the anchor, over the little pin and under the bolt? Chain logo facing out?

Comment: Yeah, the cable is routed correctly.  With the adapter off, the cable doesn't really even touch the pin.  And yes, the chain logo is facing out.  Hey, I REALLY appreciate all the suggestions.  I think we've explored just about every avenue.  Probably time to take it to the LBS.  I'll be sure to report back when I find a fix.  I'm kinda hoping I've missed something dumb and it isn't just super tough to dial in.  I have to say that SRAM is a million times easier to adjust.

Answer (score 2):

Hi did you resolve this? I had the same problem while building a bike with ultegra 6800. I found the following resolved my problem, and was detailed in the shimano manual:

-set converter to 'off'.

-attach the cable while setting the derailleur height I.e set the height over the largest chainring as detailed in the manual and only then attach the cable.

The above gave me the right tension and allowed me to reach the high and low limits.initially I just attached the cable while the derailleur was over the largest chainring which made a big improvement but it was still not perfect. I then set the converter to 'off' which made it perfect.

Comment: I was never able to resolve the problem with the 6800 derailleur.  I ended up buying the new Dura Ace R9100 and it works perfectly.  Got it right the first time and I haven't had to touch it since.  I highly recommend it.  I believe the new Ultegra level R8000 has the same design.  It has the added benefit or much better tire clearance.

Answer (score 0):

Is the front derailleur on straight and at the right height?
Set the limits all the way out and check again with the bike on a stand.
If that doesn't work, then while leaving the limits all the way out, take off the chain, and look closely to see how far the derailleur moves compared to the crankset gap.  If its about the same then your problem is NOT solved.  But if they are clearly different, then you know the problem is in how much the shifters are moving the derailleur.

You're probably thinking "impossible"!  But the last 9 speed MTB rear derailleur I bought turned out to have that problem.  Finally, I found that if I put the cable on the other side of the screw, where there was no groove and it clearly wasn't intended to go, it worked perfectly because that changed the pull ratio just right.  I never figured out why it was like that, but I am guessing that either it was dual 9 speed/10 speed, with 9 speed relegated to poor side of the screw and no explanation, or I got a wrongly labeled product.  Having got it to work, I kept it, and it's still going strong after several months.

You never know.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "see how far the derailleur moves compared to the crankset gap".  If my crankset gap is 2mm, what am I looking for as I shift up and down?